# Windows doesn't boot after boot drive change; common fixes fail

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

I used to dual-boot two Windows 7 installations – one old and the other newly installed. I wanted to get rid of the old installation, and to do so, I performed the following operations.

Using *EasyBCD*,

- I deleted the entry for the old Windows installation.
- I copied the BCD data to my new Windows partition (C: drive).

Since the old Windows partition was marked as active, I booted from the Windows Recovery CD and ran `diskpart` from the command prompt.

In *DiskPart*:

- I deleted the old Windows partition (by `delete` command).
- I marked the new Windows partition as active (by `active` command).

---

I expected to be able to boot into the new Windows installation without any futher problem, but when I tried to do so, the booting simply paused with a blank screen, with a blinking cursor at the top-left corner.

I have faced such problems once or twice before, and hence know some common fixes. From the recovery disk, I tried:

- Automatic Startup Recovery
- `bootrec /fixMBR`
- `bootrec /fixBoot`
- `bootrec /rebuildBCD`
- `bootsect /nt60 C:` (I have checked that the new Windows partition is labelled as C:).

None of these worked, and I am still stuck with the blank screen.

What to do next? Any ideas at all?

---

(I am using an old HP–Compaq laptop, with 512 MB of RAM. I have with me the original installation disk of Windows 7 Ultimate, which contains the Windows Recovery tools. If any more information is required, please comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot process is simple on MBR disks (and BIOS firmware).

1. On hard disk you need MBR and PBR of active partition in NT6 (Vista, Windows 7/8) format.

You can write this info using bootsect.exe (from Recovery console)

```
bootsect.exe /nt60 c: /MBR
```

assuming c: is active, else change drive letter.

2. You need Win 7 boot files on active partition - use bcdboot.exe

   bcdboot N:\Windows /s M:

N: is where Windows 7 is, M: is active partition in this case, same as above - change drive letters according to your mappings.

That's it.

For help you can consult [Repair Windows BCD](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html) and [Fix Windows boot](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/repair-windows-boot.html), both cover BIOS and UEFI booting, how to map active partition etc.

Comment: Thanks! I followed your advice and set the D: drive as boot partition. All problems vanished.